# predict function syntax isnt working to show the result

Tags: matlab, neural-network, predict

how to use the "predict" function in MATLAB when I have to predict an output for a 3-input and single output custom neural network?

I have tried using the predict function using Y=predict(net,50,3,10) but it says "Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs for function 'predict'."
my neural network has 3 inputs which take in 3 different numerical arrays as inputs and has a single output but this function doesnt give me any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** The third and successive input fields to predict

**1.1.** are not just numerical values but **property names** and respective **values**.

**1.2.** have to go in pairs

Other functions have the alternative of using handles on calling the funtion

`h1=func(input_data)`

and then one may change properties in structure style by doing

```
h1.property1=whatever1
h2.property2= ...
..
```

But it's not the case for `predict`, one has to use the original MATLAB way of changing properties within the funtion input field.

**2.-** example

```
[ypred,yci]=predict(mdl,Xnew,'Alpha',0.1,'Simultaneous',true)
```

**3.-** Read [Mathworks help page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.predict.html) for `predict` and use the examples provided.

**4.-** Available in MATLAB version R2013a